# jQuery cookie for toggles not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, toggle

I have created a toggle page that the majority of users access via Internet Explorer, only the cookie which should save the last state of the toggles fails to work. I have attempted to use Intellectual Tortoise's fix, which only broke the toggle functionality. And after reading over the information on the W3C site about cookies left me with a deer-in-the-headlights expression.

My issues are:

1. The last state is not working in Internet Explorer browser, any version.
2. I would like the state to persist and never expire in any browser.

The js:

```
    /toggle/
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").show();
    $("h2.trigger").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
    });
    });

    /cookies/
    $(".toggle_container").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($.cookie('show-' + this.id) != 'collapsed');
    });
    $(".trigger").click(function () {
    var tc = 
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $.cookie('show-' + $(this).attr("id"), $(this).is(":hidden") ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded');        
    });
    return false;
    });
```

The html with employer-required censure:

```
        <h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Production</a></h2>
<div class="toggle_container" id="pd">
    <div class="block">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Staff</td>
                <td>PD</td>
                <td><a href="https://snip/">https://snip/</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Service</td>
                <td>PD</td>
                <td><a href="https://snip/">https://snip/</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of the cookie plugin are you using?

Comment: I updated to the latest cookie version and the last state remains non-functional in IE.

Comment: I just took out all of the cookie code and the last state continues to work in Firefox, so I doubt the cookie code contributed anything at all.

Comment: @Sanden - Any solution to this at all?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem which is similar. I had forgot to put `{ path: "/" }` in.

```
$.cookie("DoNotShowGettingStartedDialog", true, { path: "/" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the latest jQuery cookie plugin from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie . The version on jQuery's plugin page is out of date.